# Resizing table within table iOS

Tags: ios, swift, resize, tablecell

This is a problem I've managed to solve using workarounds but haven't really understood fundamentally.

I've got a table **(table A)** with **X cells**. Each cell contains a label ( dynamic, can be any size of text, a poll question ) and a table **(table B )** with **Y poll answers**.

So essentially I do this to display a table with some poll questions and their answers.

I am not sure about the approach I should take in making sure things are resized properly. Should i just calculate the size of the dynamic label ( question ) and then calculate the size of **table B** based on the number of cells and just assign then just assign that height to that cell of **table A**?

Is there a way to set the constraints in such a way so that it can all somehow be calculated automatically using **UITableViewAutomaticDimension**?

How would you go about it? Thank you for taking the time. If there's ambiguity in my problem statement please let me know so I can clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience nested table views are problematic especially in case the height is dynamic. Do you really need table B? In case of nested table view (tableB) you lose the ability to reuse answers cells (beacuse the table B won't be scrolled).
I would recommend using UIStackView for presenting answers. It should be more straightforward in use.

Or, even better. Why don't you make single question as a section. The question label could be section header and poll answers could be made as normal cells. Nice and clean approach, good performance as answers cells can be reused.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Im being limited by a very custom UI with cards and shadows so it was a little sketchy to do it with sections.

I dont know much about stack views but would it be easy to use them and still be able to figure out which one in the stack view was selected as the desired answer and highlight them when pressed + all the other things you can normally do fairly easy with a table?

If nothing else i'm glad that someone pointed out that nested table views are problematic. I was thinking i was doing something very wrong.

Thanks again

Comment: UIStackView approach is a bit tricky as you have to handle events like selection, highlighing etc. by yourself. But this is what you already figured out. In this case the approach with questions as sections is much more handy. Maybe you could share what limitations you face with sections so that we could help you work them around or propose other solution.